# fix a line's position in the center - scaled sheets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am doing this to make a verticle line in between two numbers:

```
 <View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
    <Text style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
    <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
    <Text style={styles.numbers}>2</Text>
 </View>

  ridesFriends: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    // marginLeft: 2,
    // marginRight: 3,
    width: '100%',
  },
  numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  verticleLine: {
    height: '100%',
    width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#909090',
  }
```

However, the line doesn't appear in the exact middle. This is because 132 is longer than the number 2. If I change 132 to just 3, then the line appears in the center. Is there any way to fix the line in the middle?
[image]

Updated:
[image]

```
        <View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
          {/* <View style={styles.numbersContainer}> */}
          <Text style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
          <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
          <Text style={styles.numbers}>{numberOfFriends}</Text>
          {/* </View> */}
        </View>

  ridesFriends: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    // marginLeft: 2,
    // marginRight: 3,
    width: '100%',
  },
  numbersContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  num1: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#909090',
  },
  numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: '900',
    textShadowColor: '#000000',
    textShadowRadius: 0.5,
  },

  verticleLine: {
    height: '100%',
    width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
    //position: 'fixed',
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have set the width of the parent to 100% you can easily wrap the number texts into views and set 50% each. The code would be like below

```
    <View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
      <View style={styles.numberWrap}>
        <Text style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
      <View style={styles.numberWrap}>
        <Text style={styles.numbers}>2</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Styles

```
ridesFriends: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // marginLeft: 2,
    // marginRight: 3,
    width: '100%',
  },
  numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  verticleLine: {
    height: '100%',
    width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#909090',
  },
  numberWrap: {
    width: '50%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `View` component outside your text and style it with `flex: 1` to equal separating space for your `Text` component.

Then you can add `{alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center'}` in your Text container view to archive your component

Try mine:

```js
<View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
   <View style={styles.numbersContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
   <View style={styles.numbersContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.numbers}>2</Text>
   </View>
</View>

ridesFriends: {
    paddingTop: 70,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 20,
 },
 numbersContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
 },
 numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
 },
 verticleLine: {
    height: '100%',
    width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#909090',
 },
```

Hope that help :)

Comment: Could you see the updated picture I just added? The line becomes too large when I use your edit

Comment: I think this cause by your `ridesFriends` missing `flexDirection: 'row'` property, so it will take the `column` as the default flexDirection. Try to add it :)

Comment: Or you may update with your full code, may I take a look ?